# Facility Location Problem in python with pulp

Tags: python, pulp

I do a facility location problem solution with pulp in python, it calculates the solution path correctly, but there is a problem with the total cost.

```
from pulp import *

Customer = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Facility = ['Fac-1', 'Fac-2', 'Fac-3']
Demand = {1: 50, 2: 50, 3: 75, 4: 75}
Max_Supply = {'Fac-1': 100, 'Fac-2': 100, 'Fac-3': 500}
fixed_cost = {'Fac-1': 100.123, 'Fac-2': 100.456, 'Fac-3': 100.789}
transportation_cost = {'Fac-1': {1: 100.1, 2: 100.4, 3: 200.7, 4: 200.1}, 'Fac-2': {1: 200.2, 2: 200.5, 3: 100.8, 4: 200.11}, 'Fac-3': {1: 2000.3, 2: 2000.6, 3: 2000.9, 4: 100.12}}

prob = LpProblem("Capacitated_Facility_Location_Problem", LpMinimize)

use_facility = LpVariable.dicts("Use Facility", Facility, 0, 1, LpBinary)

ser_customer = LpVariable.dicts("Service", [(i,j) for i in Customer for j in Facility], 0)

prob += lpSum(fixed_cost[j]*use_facility[j] for j in Facility) + lpSum(transportation_cost[j][i]*ser_customer[(i,j)] for j in Facility for i in Customer)

for i in Customer:
    prob += lpSum(ser_customer[(i,j)] for j in Facility) == Demand[i]

for j in Facility:
    prob += lpSum(ser_customer[(i,j)] for i in Customer) <= Max_Supply[j]*use_facility[j]

for i in Customer:
    for j in Facility:
        prob += ser_customer[(i,j)] <= Demand[i]*use_facility[j]

for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

print("Total Cost = ", value(prob.objective))
```

## Output:

- Service_(1,_'Fac_1') = 50.0
- Service_(2,_'Fac_1') = 50.0
- Service_(3,_'Fac_2') = 75.0
- Service_(4,_'Fac_3') = 75.0
- Use_Facility_Fac_1 = 1.0
- Use_Facility_Fac_2 = 1.0
- Use_Facility_Fac_3 = 1.0
- Total Cost =  25395.368000000002

### but total cost should be like below

- transport cost = (100.1 + 100.4 + 100.8 + 100.12) =   401.42

- fixed_cost = (100.123 + 100.456 + 100.789) =          301.368
- Total Cost = 702.708

Answer (score 1):

The computer is correct....go figure.  :)

In your objective, you are multiplying the transport cost **times** the service amount.  See the last line of the output below.  Also note how you can "break up" the expression for ease in troubleshooting and then just use the parts in the objective function (or elsewhere).

```
from pulp import *

Customer = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Facility = ['Fac-1', 'Fac-2', 'Fac-3']
Demand = {1: 50, 2: 50, 3: 75, 4: 75}
Max_Supply = {'Fac-1': 100, 'Fac-2': 100, 'Fac-3': 500}
fixed_cost = {'Fac-1': 100.123, 'Fac-2': 100.456, 'Fac-3': 100.789}
transportation_cost = {'Fac-1': {1: 100.1, 2: 100.4, 3: 200.7, 4: 200.1}, 'Fac-2': {1: 200.2, 2: 200.5, 3: 100.8, 4: 200.11}, 'Fac-3': {1: 2000.3, 2: 2000.6, 3: 2000.9, 4: 100.12}}

prob = LpProblem("Capacitated_Facility_Location_Problem", LpMinimize)

use_facility = LpVariable.dicts("Use Facility", Facility, 0, 1, LpBinary)

ser_customer = LpVariable.dicts("Service", [(i,j) for i in Customer for j in Facility], 0)

fixed = lpSum(fixed_cost[j]*use_facility[j] for j in Facility)
transpo = lpSum(transportation_cost[j][i]*ser_customer[(i,j)] for j in Facility for i in Customer)  
prob += fixed + transpo

for i in Customer:
    prob += lpSum(ser_customer[(i,j)] for j in Facility) == Demand[i]

for j in Facility:
    prob += lpSum(ser_customer[(i,j)] for i in Customer) <= Max_Supply[j]*use_facility[j]

for i in Customer:
    for j in Facility:
        prob += ser_customer[(i,j)] <= Demand[i]*use_facility[j]

prob.solve()
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

print("Total Cost = ", value(prob.objective))
print(f'fixed: {value(fixed)}')
print(f'transpo: {value(transpo)}')
t = transportation_cost["Fac-1"][1] * ser_customer[1, "Fac-1"].varValue
print(f'the transpo for fac 1 to cust 1 is: {t}')
```

#### Output:

```
Service_(1,_'Fac_1') = 50.0
Service_(2,_'Fac_1') = 50.0
Service_(3,_'Fac_2') = 75.0
Service_(4,_'Fac_3') = 75.0
Use_Facility_Fac_1 = 1.0
Use_Facility_Fac_2 = 1.0
Use_Facility_Fac_3 = 1.0
Total Cost =  25395.368000000002
fixed: 301.368
transpo: 25094.0
the transpo for fac 1 to cust 1 is: 5005.0
```

Comment: Do you have any advice I can do so that I can get the output I want?

Comment: Yep....  Well, I'm inferring from your desired output that you want transport to be a "fixed cost" based on route usage.  So, the missing piece is that you will need an *additional* binary variable, indexed by (cust, fac) to indicate that route is used.  You are very close!  Set it up similar to how you are using your other binary variable, such that `ser_customer[c, f] <= use_route[c, f] * max_supply[f]`.  Make sense?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said (I guess my English wasn't enough ^^), do you have a chance to post this as a code?

Comment: Give it a try.  You are on the right track and I don't want to do *all* of your homework for you! ;)

Comment: i got caught ^^, thank you for your help. I don't know the rules of the site, should this answer be marked as an answer?